# Wait for user response after showing modal popup login

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In my code behind file i am calling an html modal popup which prompts the user for their username and password.
i would like to get a result back from this to my code behind calling function before proceeding.
how do i do this? Right now the modal form is shown and the c# code continues processing which makes sense but its not what i want.
Note: The modal signoff html modal form has a button (btnSignoff) that calls some other code behind function
thanks
Damo

**Code behind:**

```
SignoffModal.Show();
//Wait for response (this is what i would like to be able to do)
if (result <0)
{
//throw some error
}

else
{
// Do some more work
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
 <!-- Signoff Modal Form -->
                <asp:HiddenField ID="SignoffForModal" runat="server" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="SignoffModal" BehaviorID="modalPopupExtenderSignoff"
                    TargetControlID="SignoffForModal" PopupControlID="popUpPaneSignoff" OkControlID="btnSignoff"
                    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                <asp:Panel ID="popUpPaneSignoff" runat="server" CssClass="confirm-dialog">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" ToolTip="Username" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" ToolTip="Password" TextMode="Password"
                        Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="base">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSignoff" runat="server" Text="Signoff" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CssClass="close" OnClientClick="$find('modalPopupExtenderSignoff').hide(); return false;" /></div>
                </asp:Panel>
                <!-- End Signoff Modal Form -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `ModalPopupExtender` isn't designed this way.  While it is *modal* (prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the page), it's not *blocking*, mean code continues to run after the form is called.    That's because the popup is running on the client, and the code-behind runs the server. This is called a [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) because the client code *calls back* to the server when a action is taken.

To make this work, you have to split the logic you after `SignoffModal.Show();` in an "Ok" part and a "Cancel" part by adding a `CancelControlID` attribute on `ModalPopupExtender` to point to the button that handles the Cancel action, then add the button:

```
  <!-- Signoff Modal Form -->
<asp:HiddenField ID="SignoffForModal" runat="server" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="SignoffModal" 
    BehaviorID="modalPopupExtenderSignoff"
    TargetControlID="SignoffForModal" 
    PopupControlID="popUpPaneSignoff"     
    OkControlID="btnSignoff" 
 // points to cancel button action
    CancelControlID="btnCancel" 
 BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
```

...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSignoff" runat="server" Text="Signoff" />
    // handles Cancel action...
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    ...
<!-- End Signoff Modal Form -->
```

---

in  the `btnSignoff` code-behind event handler:

```
{
// Do some work...
```

in  the `btnCancel` code-behind event handler:

```
{
//throw some error...
```

Comment: Hi,so basically you are saying: It is not possible and that i have to continue processing using the code behind for btnsignoff. i can do this but id like the signoff modal + its code behind to be reuseable for other situations where i want username and password signoff. Is this correct as to what you are saying?

Comment: You can still make the code reusable, it's just that you'll have to wire up the code the way the ModalPopupExtender expects. This means having one block of code for Ok and another for Cancel.  just make functions for each, and then in other apps call the functions in from the button even handler.

Comment: i ended up setting a session variable to a value on the first function. Then i check what that session variable is set to and run through a list of switch statements to execute the required function when this second function is called.